# One solution multiple projects debug folder

Tags: visual-studio-2008, mfc

I recently learnt about the benefits of one solution with multiple projects. Suppose I have 3 projects A, B and C, all of which create a .exe application file. I first created a blank solution, added all three existing projects and built the solution. Now, there is a debug folder which gets created under the solution folder. This debug folder contains all the files that are created from building the three projects. The three projects already each have a debug folder. I don't want the debug folder under the solution folder. Can anyone explain to me how to do that? Is it possible? Thanks!
I use VS2008

Comment: Change the location of $OutPutDir in project settings of all project.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I just had to change the output directory.